# Can not access in local server on mac by IP address with phone

Tags: localhost, webserver, ip-address

1. I create a web server on mac and I can view it on `127.0.0.1:5173`.
2. I make true that mac and my phone are in a same WiFi.
3. I find mac's IP address by ifconfig: `192.168.3.255`.
   [image: website on mac]
4. But, it doesn't work on my phone when I type in `192.168.3.255:5173` in my phone's browser.
   [image: ipaddress]

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Is your phone on wifi?  Does it also have an IP address starting with '192.168.3'?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is that Vue3 use the tool: vite, when you need to open it on the phone by ip address, you should type "npm run vite --host".

The "--host" can expose it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `inet` IP shown in this output? `192.168.3.13`

Comment: I had tried that, it didn't work too.

Comment: Hi James, I cannot comment since I don't have enough reputation. Apologies if this was in the wrong place.